Library or Offline Model for Accurate Arabic-to-English Translation (Including Dialects)
I'm looking for a Python library (that doesn’t use API) or offline model that can accurately translate Arabic text to English, including text from different dialects. Are there any pre-trained models available that are specifically designed for handling Arabic dialects?
I want it to have offline translation capabilities (no internet connection required) and high accuracy in translation, particularly for dialectal variations.
I appreciate any insights or recommendations from the community.
